# PHP PDF generation problem

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

i have used FPDF for creating pdf in PHP.

I used session variable to pass the variable between one form to another form. When i provide a value in the

```
    Report.php
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['year1']=$_POST['course_year'];
    $_SESSION['sem1']=$_POST['semester'];
    $_SESSION['community1']=$_POST['community'];
    $_SESSION['course1']=$_POST['course'];
    $_SESSION['mess_type1']=$_POST['mess_type'];
    $_SESSION['block_name1']=$_POST['block_name'];
    ?>        
    <form action='report.php' method='POST'name= 'form1'>
        <p><tr><td><b> Course Year:</b></td><td><input type='text' name='course_year'></td></tr><br></p>
        <p><tr><td> &nbsp;</td><td><input style='width:105;height:32' type='submit'  value='Generate Report'onsubmit='yearpdf.php' onclick="year_open()" ></td></tr>
        </form>
    <h2 align='left'><b>Semester</h2></b>
    <form action='report.php' method='POST'name= 'form2'>
    <!--<form action='report.php' align='left' method='POST'>-->
    <p><b><tr><td>Semester:</b></td><td><input type='text' name='semester'></td></tr><br></p>
    <p><tr><td> &nbsp;</td><td><input style='width:105;height:32' type='submit'  value='Generate Report' onsubmit='sempdf.php' onclick="sem_open()"></td></tr></table>
    </form>
.... so on for community, course, messtype and blockname
```

where yearpdf.php is the file which i have written for the creation of pdf file. As soon as the pdf is generated Blank values with tables are displayed. I have to refresh to get the values displayed in the PDF. My yearpdf file is :

```
    <?php
session_start();
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

//Connect to your database

$r1=$_SESSION['year1'];

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

if(!$con)
{
die('Unable to connect'.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('hostel',$con);

//Select the list you want to show in your PDF file
$result=mysql_query("select hosteladmissionno,student_name,sex,community,semester,course,course_year,mess_type,block_name from registration where course_year='".$r1."' ORDER BY hosteladmissionno");

$number_of_products = mysql_numrows($result);



//For each row, add the field to the corresponding column
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $hostad = $row['hosteladmissionno'];
    $name = $row['student_name'];
    $sex = $row['sex'];
    $sem=$row['semester'];
    $comm=$row['community'];
    $course=$row['course'];
    $courseyr=$row['course_year'];
    $mess= $row['mess_type'];
    $block=$row['block_name'];



    $column_no = $column_no.$hostad."\n";
    $column_name = $column_name.$name."\n";
    $sex_details = $sex_details.$sex."\n";
    $sem_details= $sem_details.$sem."\n";
    $comm_details= $comm_details.$comm."\n";
    $course_details= $course_details.$course."\n";
    $courseyr_details= $courseyr_details.$courseyr."\n";
    $mess_details= $mess_details.$mess."\n";
    $block_details= $block_details.$block."\n";
    //$column_price = $column_price.$price_to_show."\n";


}
mysql_close();

//Convert the Total Price to a number with (.) for thousands, and (,) for decimals.
//$total = number_format($total,',','.','.');

//Create a new PDF file
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

//Fields Name position
$Y_Fields_Name_position = 40;
//Table position, under Fields Name
$Y_Table_Position = 46;

//First create each Field Name
//Gray color filling each Field Name box
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
//Bold Font for Field Name
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Fields_Name_position);
$pdf->SetX(5);
$pdf->Cell(30,6,'Admission No',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(35);
$pdf->Cell(35,6,'Student Name',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(70);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'Sex',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(88);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'Category',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(108);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'Semester',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(128);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'Course',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(145);
$pdf->Cell(15,6,'Year',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(160);
$pdf->Cell(25,6,'Mess type',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->SetX(185);
$pdf->Cell(25,6,'Block Name',1,0,'L',1);
$pdf->Ln();

//Now show the 3 columns
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(5);
$pdf->MultiCell(30,6,$column_no,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(35);
$pdf->MultiCell(35,6,$column_name,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(70);
$pdf->MultiCell(18,6,$sex_details,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(88);
$pdf->MultiCell(20,6,$comm_details,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(108);
$pdf->MultiCell(20,6,$sem_details,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(128);
$pdf->MultiCell(17,6,$course_details,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(145);
$pdf->MultiCell(15,6,$courseyr_details,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(160);
$pdf->MultiCell(25,6,$mess_details,1);
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
$pdf->SetX(185);
$pdf->MultiCell(25,6,$block_details,1);



$i = 0;
$pdf->SetY($Y_Table_Position);
while ($i < $number_of_products)
{
    $pdf->SetX(5);
    $pdf->MultiCell(205,6,'',1);
    $i = $i +1;
}

$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: are you having problem in generating pdf or getting values before writing to pdf.

Comment: also please shorten you question like the other and alert me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form `onsubmit` seems to be wrong. `onsubmit` should be a `javascript function`  not a `php file`. if you need to submit to php file you should use `action` attribute of `form`. currently you have given it as `report.php`. you may need to change it to `yearpdf.php` or redirect in the `report.php`

EDIT 1:

the problem is you are calling the `window.open` which opens an url but doesn't submit your input value. so first time nothing will happen. but however on the next `window.open` or on the next refresh, there is  the session variable from report.php and thus retrieves the data. you can follow some options

1. put the code of report.php that to process the submit in yearpdf.php and change the form "action" to the yearpdf.php. and remove onclick function
2. OR Redirect from report.php to yearpdf.php in the end of report.php. For redirect you can use `header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/yearpdf.php');`. and remove onclick function
3. OR modfiy your JavaScript code to send something like this `window.open("yearpdf.php" + "?course_year=" + document.getElementsByName("course_year")[0].value));` and change your `$r1=$_SESSION['year1'];` to `$r1=$_GET['course_year'];` in yearpdf.php

Option 1 is the recommended and simple way. Option 2 is an overhead and won't work if you output any html before redirection. and Option 3 produces an unnecessary window.

Comment: <?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['year1']=$_POST['course_year'];
?> ( Im using this session varialble in the first form, i.e the form which containts the HTML code which you typed it now)

Comment: hmm.. well that's odd. can you post report.php also?

Comment: this feels like a problem of `messing with session` because it works on refersh

Comment: Yeah!! exactly.. I have done something wrong with sessions. Dont know who to fix it.

Comment: you can edit your question and add report.php too. and what is that `year_open()` in the `onclick` ?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function year_open()
{
window.open("yearpdf.php");
}
</script>

Comment: aha.. i got that. you are actually not submitting the data to report.php. instead you are opening yearpdf.php directly

Comment: to redirect use `header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/yearpdf.php');` in the end. but is there any output produced for `report.php`?

Comment: but that's a bad way. why are you using two forms? report.php and yearpdf.php. what is use of report.php?

Comment: Im producing the output in pdf by passing the session from report.php to yearpdf.php.Adding to that im having more forms.. like semester, mess type and block name etc in report.php

Comment: hmm... you are actually doing it in the wrong way. i will edit my answer.

Comment: Hello mahesh, If i wanna Include the code from report.php to the yearpdf.php. How do i do it? Its showing the pdf file. Im not able to enter the value and get the result in pdf document.

Comment: you need only change the processing code inside the report.php to yearpdf.php(ie what happens to the post). if you show me the report.php in the question. then i can tell more

Comment: I have edited my Question for Report.php. Pls have a look, Mahesh!

Comment: Dinzy, where are you using $_SESSION['sem1'] and $_SESSION['community1']. in yearpdf.php?

Comment: what's happening? which method you choose? i think option one would have been the best for you. because there was **no processing** in report.php other than declaration of session variables. you only needed o change form `action` to `yearpdf.php` and the `$r1` as `$r1=$_POST['course_year'];`. right?

Comment: Mahesh. I did it in your way which you told. It worked! :) Im getting all the values properly and i have avoided using session. Thanks a lot Mahesh.