# Redirecting the page during session in PHP

Tags: php, session, session-state, session-variables

How to redirect after the submit button, Note: The Redirection to another page must carry the session variables from previous file and then display in the redirected page.

Comment: Why do you ask twice the same? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403557/page-redirect-during-session-passing-in-php

Comment: I thought Users will feel too vague when they read my previous post..so i shortened the question to get quick suggestions.

Comment: you can edit posts, no need to re-post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you redirect after submitting a form, it's because, if your hit `F5` button, you form is resubmitted again and again.

This is done in follwing ways,

1. Set session value
2. Use header function to redirect

   ```
   //if the submit button is pressed

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   session_start(); //also can be done before it

   $_SESSION['somevalue'] = "somevalue";

   header('location: somepage.php');
   }
   ```

Comment: lol ... looks like i got lucky. I never get code running without testing.

Comment: @Dinzy sure !!! you are welcome. Please delete your previous question if no one has answered. I will vote this question up.

Comment: Yep. Its deleted. Thanks for it. Thumbs up!:)

Comment: Hey expermientix. Do you know how to display the Text in Fpdf using Php. have a look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374329/php-pdf-generation-problem In the coding part of yearpdf.php.. How to display titles and write Text in pdf file?

Comment: @Dinzy sure also check on php on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ you might find people who could help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("location:somefile.php");
```

To carry session variable make sure you have used `session_start` in `somefile.php`

`session_start();` call that function at the top of file.